# Unable to send emails through Mandrill

Tags: asp.net, email, mandrill

I'm using Mandrill API for sending emails.

I'm sending a `webrequest` to `Send` method for sending emails. It is
working fine in my local. When I moved the code into production server, 
I'm getting the follwing error:

```
The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
```

Inner exception is:

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: Unable to find an entry point named 'EnumerateSecurityPackagesW' in DLL 'security.dll'.
 at System.Net.UnsafeNclNativeMethods.SafeNetHandles_SECURITY.EnumerateSecurityPackagesW(Int32& pkgnum, SafeFreeContextBuffer_SECURITY& handle)
 at System.Net.SafeFreeContextBuffer.EnumeratePackages(SecurDll Dll, Int32& pkgnum, SafeFreeContextBuffer& pkgArray)
 at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.EnumerateSecurityPackages(SSPIInterface SecModule)
 at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.GetVerifyPackageInfo(SSPIInterface secModule, String packageName, Boolean throwIfMissing)
 at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel..ctor(String hostname, Boolean serverMode, SchProtocols protocolFlags, X509Certificate serverCertificate, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, Boolean remoteCertRequired, Boolean checkCertName, Boolean checkCertRevocationStatus, EncryptionPolicy encryptionPolicy, LocalCertSelectionCallback certSelectionDelegate)
 at System.Net.Security.SslState.ValidateCreateContext(Boolean isServer, String targetHost, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, X509Certificate serverCertificate, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, Boolean remoteCertRequired, Boolean checkCertRevocationStatus, Boolean checkCertName)
 at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
 at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
 at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
 at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
```

My Production Server environment is:

```
OS: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard
Hosting Environment: IIS7
```

Please help me in resolving the issue as it's a work stoppage for me.

Comment: Did you check for copies of security.dll as per [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10980409/55487)?